# How to queue requests in a Django API that is running on Amazon EC2 so they are processed sequentially

Tags: linux, rest, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'd like to make it so that there are a maximum of x requests processing at one time and other requests that come in can be queued in. Is there a way to do it all in EC2? If the queue isn't possible, is it possible to check, in EC2 if the api is processing a request and if so, turn away some other incoming request?

Thank You

I tried looking for other ways to do it but all of them rely on Amazon SQS or celery or job clients. I would prefer a simpler way of doing it all in EC2 for example if there were a way to check on the OS-level whether the api is processing a request